# How to "reinstall" the audio subsystem on kubuntu?

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

How do I reinstall the audio subsystem, or whatever it's called these days?

Running kubuntu 17.10 on an 2017-model i7 Intel NUC. The thing was running fine, even outputting audio through the monitor's speaker, until it no longer was. I cannot figure out what it was that I did that killed the audio, whether it was some `apt upgrade` or whether it was installing something else, but I have not been able to bring it back, and I really do not want to reinstall the entire workstation. Yes, I have backups, but it will still be annoying.

It's not a permissions issue; `/dev/snd/*` are all 660 and I'm in the right group (`audio`). Here is the output of `lspci`, `aplay`, and `arecord`. Everything seems good, yet no devices appear in the Multimedia tab of Settings, nor will vlc or any other audio or video player play any sound.

```
# lspci -v
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 142
    Region 0: Memory at dc340000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 4: Memory at dc320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
            Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=55mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
            Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
            Address: 00000000fee004d8  Data: 0000
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl


$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


$ arecord -l | sed -e 's/^/    /'
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The output of `alsa-info` is huge, but I can post it if someone thinks it would help with the debugging

Comment: You could upload it using `pastebinit` and post the link in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other programs running that use sound?  I have one program that "steals" all of the audio subsytem and no other programs can play sound until I close that one program.

Almost all programs use sounds so think carefully about what else is running, especially background things.